# How get value with soapui (groovy) from a xml with equals tags but differents attributes

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, soapui

I'm making an automated script in groovy that gets data from a SOLR and then set that data in properties for future use.
I'm using the script assertion to do this 'cause reduce the quantity of steps in the suit.
The problem is: the XML received from SOLR has the same name in all the data, the only difference is the attribute "name".
I want to get the values by the attribute.

I've tried with xmlSlurper and XmlHolder but I can't get only one value, only get an array of data (SOLR can answer in randomly order the doc, so I can't use this solution).

The answer of SOLR is like this:

```xml
<response>
  <doc>
    <str name="Destination">6</str>
    <str name="BUS">0</str>
    <str name="Tax">N</str>
    <str name="Passage">N</str>
    <str name="Vendor">2301</str>
    <str name="id">1135XV942220</str>
  </doc>
</response>
```

I've tried:

```
def resp = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def results = resp.response.doc.find {it.name()=="BUS"}?.text()
```

this get me nothing.

```
def results = resp.response.doc.str.'@name'.text().equals('BUS')
```

Get me the value false (?)

I want to get, for example, the id and transfer it to a property at test suite level.
Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

With XmlHolder...

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
resp = new XmlHolder(context.response)
log.info resp.getNodeValue("//response/doc/str[@name='BUS']")
```